# How to create an Access Point from the current WiFi connection?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireless-networking, hotspot, internet-sharing

On Ubuntu 14.04, can an adapter have both a hotspot and be connected to a WiFi network at the same time?

If so, how do I share the Internet of the currently connected network over a hotspot in Linux?

If not, why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> can an adapter have both a hotspot and be connected to a WiFi network at the same time?

Yes , it's possible to create a hotspot wifi from the same wifi connection

> How do I share the Internet of the currently connected network over a hotspot in Linux?

You should use [`create_ap`](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap)

Install the dependencies :

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq haveged hostapd build-essential
```

To install `create_ap` run:

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create_ap
sudo make install
```

**enable/start the service:**

```
service create_ap start
```

To check the status run:

```
service create_ap status
```

Using the `systemd` features (it is not available on Ubuntu 14.04):

```
sudo systemctl start create_ap.service
sudo systemctl enable create_ap.service
```

**Create the AP**

To create your access point run:

```
sudo create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

[Update for Ubuntu 14.04](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/06/how-to-set-up-wireless-hotspot-access.html):

> the `hostapd` version in Ubuntu 14.04 is buggy and doesn't work properly. To get AP-Hotspot to work with `hostapd` in Ubuntu 14.04, you need to downgrade `hostapd` and use `apt` to hold the package so it's not upgraded.

Remove the current version of `hostapd`:

```
sudo apt-get remove hostapd
```

**64bit**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

**32bit**

```
cd /tmp
wget http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wpa/hostapd_1.0-3ubuntu2.1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i hostapd*.deb
sudo apt-mark hold hostapd
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, But there's one small problem though. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and it seems like systemctl cannot be used. Is there any other known alternative to this command?

Comment: It also disconnects itself from initially connected network. So effectively only the hotspot is created, without any internet sharing.  Here's the output from my terminal : http://pastebin.com/rEBgLBtc

Comment: @Raghav It work very well for you , just keep the running terminal openned.

Comment: Yes, the hotspot gets created, but my computer which is connected to Wi-Fi disconnects itself from the AP (WiFi-Router). Only after that, the hotspot turns on. Thus there is no internet connection on my computer's hotspot which I created from this script. 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KnBNTE40VJg

Comment: @Raghav I edit my answer , check the current version of `hostapd` with `hostapd -v` then downgrade it

Comment: Is this applicable to `Ubuntu 16.04` ?

Comment: @RoCk it work without downgrading hostapd

Comment: For me this worked also for a 'wwan0' interface connected to the internet.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488588/how-do-i-connect-to-multiple-wifi-networks).

Basically, find your wifi interface, then `sudo iw dev wlp8s0 interface add wlp8s1 type station` to create the new interface.

You can use this method to create a virtual interface, use one interface to connect to a network and use another one to create an ad-hoc network for hotspot. This should be pretty straight-forward (googling, of course), since NetworkManager has (a nice) UI. For example, [this should do it](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/09/3-ways-create-wifi-hotspot-ubuntu/).

Answer (score -1):

Just try this one, I found this working in my `Windows 10 PC` while my PC is connected to my internet, it also serves as a server (host) during my `Android` development.

Install `WINE` (Ubuntu Store) in your `Ubuntu 14.04` it makes `.exe` runs on `Ubuntu`.

And [Run](http://newtecharticles.com/downloads/wlan-launcher/) this one `WLAN Launcher` which will make your PC - turn to Hotspot mode (host).

Provide a password you like and network name. Then `Start` .

[image: WLAN]

Comment: I might as well resort to Windows for this!

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Wine is an emulator for running .exe files. Doing that everytime I wanna create a hotspot is a pain in the ass. What I asked in my question was, was there a way to create a hotspot using Linux itself. Anyway, thank you for your response. :)

Comment: Oopps, I didn't noticed. But did you try this one? Did it work?